# The parabola $x^2=12y$ rolls without slipping around the parabola $x^2=-12y$

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

The parabola $x^2=12y$ rolls without slipping around the parabola $x^2=-12y$ then find the locus of focus of rolling parabola and also find the locus of vertex of rolling parabola

Comment: Since the parabolas are the same shape, the "rolling" parabola will always be the reflection of the stationary parabola over the tangent line at the point of contact.

Comment: Think of the given position as an initial position. Once the first parabola starts rolling, it will no longer be at the indicated position.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=(x, x^2/12)$ be a point on the initial position of the rolling parabola: it will eventually touch the static parabola at $A'=(x, -x^2/12)$. The tangent at $A'$ is the bisector of $\angle CA'A$, where $C=(-3,0)$ is the focus of the static parabola and the rolling parabola (dashed blue in the diagram) is the reflection of the static parabola about the tangent.

The focus $C'$ of the rolling parabola is then the reflection of $C$ about the tangent: it thus belongs to line $AA'$ and $A'C'=A'C$. That means that $C'$ belongs to the directrix of the static parabola, i.e. to line $y=3$, which is then the desired locus.

To find the locus of $V'$, the vertex of the rolling parabola, notice that it is the midpoint of $C'F$, perpendicular to the directrix $CF$ of the rolling parabola. It follows that $C'V'$ is parallel to $CA'$ and $C'V'=CV=3$. We can then compute:
$$
V'=C'+3{\vec{A'C}\over A'C}=(x,3)
+{3\over 3+x^2/12}(-x,-3+x^2/12)={1\over 36+x^2}(x^3, 6x^2).
$$
This is the parametric equation of a [Cissoid of Diocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cissoid_of_Diocles#As_a_pedal_curve) generated by the circle of center $(0,3)$ and radius $3$.

[image]

Comment: why rolling parabola is reflection of static parabola?

Comment: @mathophile At start those two parabolas are the reflection of each other about the common tangent. The rolling condition ensures that the common point is located at the same relative position on both parabolas. Hence they preserve the reflection property at all positions.

Comment: at start it is obvious but is there any document which prove mathematically that it will be reflection at other point also?

Comment: since whole parabola is reflection about common tangent so vertex of moving parabola too will be image of vertex of fixed parabola isn't it?

Comment: @mathophile Yes, of course. Re math proof: as I explained above, the reflected parabola is tangent at $A'$ and parabolic arcs $A'V$, $A'V'$ have the same length, which are the conditions for rolling without slipping.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

\begin{align}
\text{Static parabola: }f(x)&=-\tfrac1{12}x^2
,\\
f'(x)&=-\tfrac1{6}x
.
\end{align}

Tangent line at $x=x_t$: 
\begin{align}
f_t(x,x_t)&=
f'(x_t)\,(x-x_t)+f(x_t)
\\
&=
-\tfrac1{6}x_t\,(x-x_t)-\tfrac1{12}x_t^2
\\
&=
-\tfrac16\,x_t\,x+\tfrac1{12}\,x_t^2
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
|OD|&=\tfrac12x_t \quad\text{(why?)}
,\\
\tan\theta&=\tfrac16\,x_t
,\\
\sin\theta&=
\frac{\tan\theta}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}}
=\frac{x_t}{\sqrt{x_t^2+36}}
,\\
\cos\theta&=
\frac{6}{\sqrt{x_t^2+36}}
,\\
|OO'|&=2|OD|\sin\theta
=\frac{x_t^2}{\sqrt{x_t^2+36}}
,\\
O'_x&=|OO'|\,\cos(90^\circ-\theta)=|OB|\,\sin\theta
=\frac{x_t^3}{x_t^2+36}
,\\
O'_y&=|OO'|\,\sin(90^\circ-\theta)=|OB|\,\cos\theta
=
\frac{6x_t^2}{x_t^2+36}
.\\
\end{align}

Hence, the locus of vertex of rolling parabola 
is defined parametrically as

\begin{align}
O'(x_t)&=
\left(\frac{t^3}{t^2+36}, \frac{6t^2}{t^2+36}\right)
,\quad t\in\mathbb{R}
.
\end{align}

This can be used as a base to derive the locus of the rolling focus.

Comment: The implicitization of $(x,y)=(\frac{t^3}{t^2+36},\frac{6t^2}{t^2+36})$ is $x^2y+y^3-6x^2=0$. In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/): `R=QQ[s,t,x,y,z]`
`I=ideal(x-t^3,y-6*s*t^2,z-(s*t^2+s^3*36))` `gens gb I`, yields `x2y+y3-6x2z`.